# Symfony2: Show IP as string and save IP as INT

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, ip

I have an Entity in Symfony called Ip and I save my IP address as integer - I use the IP as primary key, too.

But when I display and enter the IP in a form or list I want to convert it to a IP, e.g. 127.0.0.1 is saved as 2130706433.

I created the forms with the CRUD generator.

My entity comes here:

```
<?php

namespace IS\ClearanceBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * IS\ClearanceBundle\Entity\Ip
*/
class Ip
{
/**
 * @var bigint $ip
 */
private $ip;

/**
 * @var integer $high
 */
private $high;

/**
 * @var string $hoster
 */
private $hoster;

/**
 * @var datetime $scandate
 */
private $scandate;

/**
 * @var integer $id
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var IS\ClearanceBundle\Entity\Clearance
 */
private $clearance;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->clearance = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Set ip
 *
 * @param bigint $ip
 */
public function setIp($ip)
{
    $this->ip = $ip;
}


/**
 * Get ip
 *
 * @return bigint
 */
public function getIp()
{
    return $this->ip;
}


/**
 * Set high
 *
 * @param integer $high
 */
public function setHigh($high)
{
    $this->high = $high;
}

/**
 * Get high
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getHigh()
{
    return $this->high;
}

/**
 * Set hoster
 *
 * @param string $hoster
 */
public function setHoster($hoster)
{
    $this->hoster = $hoster;
}

/**
 * Get hoster
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getHoster()
{
    return $this->hoster;
}

/**
 * Set scandate
 *
 * @param datetime $scandate
 */
public function setScandate($scandate)
{
    $this->scandate = $scandate;
}

/**
 * Get scandate
 *
 * @return datetime
 */
public function getScandate()
{
    return $this->scandate;
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Add clearance
 *
 * @param IS\ClearanceBundle\Entity\Clearance $clearance
 */
public function addClearance(\IS\ClearanceBundle\Entity\Clearance $clearance)
{
    $this->clearance[] = $clearance;
}

/**
 * Get clearance
 *
 * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getClearance()
{
    return $this->clearance;
}
}
```

And here is my Controller:

```
<?php

namespace IS\ClearanceBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use IS\ClearanceBundle\Entity\Ip;
use IS\ClearanceBundle\Form\IpType;

/**
* Ip controller.
*
* @Route("/ip")
*/
class IpController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Lists all Ip entities.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="ip")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('ISClearanceBundle:Ip')->findAll();

    return array('entities' => $entities);
}

/**
 * Finds and displays a Ip entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/show", name="ip_show")
 * @Template()
 */
public function showAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('ISClearanceBundle:Ip')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Ip entity.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),        );
}

/**
 * Displays a form to create a new Ip entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="ip_new")
 * @Template()
 */
public function newAction()
{
    $entity = new Ip();
    $form   = $this->createForm(new IpType(), $entity);

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView()
    );
}

/**
 * Creates a new Ip entity.
 *
 * @Route("/create", name="ip_create")
 * @Method("post")
 * @Template("ISClearanceBundle:Ip:new.html.twig")
 */
public function createAction()
{
    $entity  = new Ip();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form    = $this->createForm(new IpType(), $entity);
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ip_show', array('id' => $                                                                            entity->getId())));

    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form'   => $form->createView()
    );
}

/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Ip entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="ip_edit")
 * @Template()
 */
public function editAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('ISClearanceBundle:Ip')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Ip entity.');
    }

    $editForm = $this->createForm(new IpType(), $entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Edits an existing Ip entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/update", name="ip_update")
 * @Method("post")
 * @Template("ISClearanceBundle:Ip:edit.html.twig")
 */
public function updateAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('ISClearanceBundle:Ip')->find($id);

    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Ip entity.');
    }

    $editForm   = $this->createForm(new IpType(), $entity);
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $editForm->bindRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ip_edit', array('id' => $                                                                            id)));
    }

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}

/**
 * Deletes a Ip entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/delete", name="ip_delete")
 * @Method("post")
 */
public function deleteAction($id)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $form->bindRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $entity = $em->getRepository('ISClearanceBundle:Ip')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Ip entity.'                                                                            );
        }

        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ip'));
}

private function createDeleteForm($id)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder(array('id' => $id))
        ->add('id', 'hidden')
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
}
```

And here the form:

```
 <?php

 namespace IS\ClearanceBundle\Form;

 use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
 use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

 class IpType extends AbstractType
 {
 public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
 {
    $builder
        ->add('ip')
        ->add('high')
        ->add('hoster')
        ->add('scandate')
        ->add('clearance','entity', array('class'=>'IS\ClearanceBundle\Entity\Clearance', 'property'=>'id','required'=>false, 'multiple'=>true))
    ;
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'is_clearancebundle_iptype';
}
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: a "real IP" won't fit into an int. You are restricting yourself to old style, legacy IPv4s.

Comment: That's ok for me. I use it only for private IP address ranges and no IPv6

Comment: @glglgl, well it will not fit in a native PHP int but it is still convertible to a big int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMO if you want do it, you should use data transformer http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html and implement __toString for your entity IP.

EDIT:

Created sample at gist: https://gist.github.com/3086241

Comment: Hi, that helped a bit. If you can modify your answer with an example I can mark it as accepted answer

Comment: Thanks, that helps more. But I'm a little confused. Why are there 2 types (IpType.php and IpExampleType.php)? I tried it both ways and got one time "Circular reference detected in the "ip" type (defined in class "IS\ClearanceBundle\Form\IpType")" and the other one "Warning: long2ip() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /var/www/Symfony/src/IS/ClearanceBundle/Form/DataTransformer/IptoIntTransformer.php ". Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: IpType is just custom type for IP transformation handling. IPExampleType (this is basically type you should use with your object) using IpType as you see `$builder->add('ip', 'ip')`, just like normal text type. Types should have different names of course. And you should register new custom type in service.yml too

Comment: Curious as to why not just use the model getter/setter to convert the value to `$this->ip = ip2long($ip ?: '') ?: null` and back to `return long2ip($this->ip ?: '') ?: null`? However you could create a [custom mapping type](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html) `ip_address`. that you can use in the ORM to maintain migrations for using the `VARBINARY(16)` data-type and handle the conversion to/from database values for any entity.